# How Magento 2(Any website) will transfer order details to payment Gateway

Tags: magento2, payment, payment-gateway

Today I just went around Magento 2 payment page. To know how the website will transfer order details from Magento 2 to payment Gateway page. But here I can see only the `radio buttons` and **other stuff** like `text boxes`, `labels` etc...

[image]

[image]

I know how the payment process will [done](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/payment-gateway/payment-gateway-intro.html) functionally. 
**And what are all the form tag contains like `form` tag, `text boxes`, `form key`,.. etc?**

**But how the website will transfer the order details to payment gateway?**

looking for the brief answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know How Magento transfer data especially in your case(Paypal)

You can debug this class

```
Magento\Paypal\Gateway\Payflowpro\Command\SaleCommand
```

In this class you will find execute method where magento sends data as request

And debugging this class you will know how magento passes data to paypal

Answer (score 2):

that largely depends on your payment gateway and the protocol it enforces upon you.

In your example you are using paypal so data can move two ways to paypal and back from paypal to your site and

- to paypal part: this is done on php level with remote requests to gateway and you get back a url or token to build a url to redirect your customer to
- back from paypal: data is just posted to your site endpoint or requested with webrequest (like rates request)

Comment: Give a simple example with code?

Comment: open up paypal extenion codebase , all examples you can get are right there